# ia32-libs-gtk package not found

Tags: 14.04, apt

Though I searched a lot and there are lots of thread about **ia32-libs-gtk** but nothing seems to solve the problem.

when I ran 
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk`
 it says **unable to locate**.

i want to install  **Forticlient SSL VPN**  and for installing it the first step is installing ia32-libs-gtk Help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer to my own question.
I tested it on ubuntu 14.04 and works smoothly.
Just run the below commands in order
Just you need sudo rights for this

1. `cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d`
2. `sudo echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" > ia32-libs-raring.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: Thank you. Tried all else. Nothing worked but this one.

Answer (score 4):

With multiarch you need to explicitly install i386 packages needed, ex.

`sudo apt-get  install libgtk2.0-0:i386`

Otherwise maybe have a look here for alt. packaging - https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/